# identity server 4 does not show all user claims

Tags: c#, identityserver4

I'm using IdentityServer4 and everything is fine until I log in with some user, where all my user data does not appear.

When entering a TestUser with the name, email, website, age, game-favorite Claims, it only displays the name and website.

how do I display all the variants my user has?

```
return new List < TestUser > {
 new TestUser {
  SubjectId = "2",
   Username = "bob",
   Password = "password",
   Claims = new [] {
    new Claim("name", "Bob Asterman"),
     new Claim("e-mail", "bobasterman@gmail.com"),
     new Claim("website", "https://bob.com"),
     new Claim("idade", "25 anos"),
     new Claim("jogo-favorito", "nier-automata")
   }
 }
};
```

Sorry for the bad English.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Claim `idade` is not included by default. you need to introduce this as a custom claim by adding it your Scopes in `GetScopes` method in the config.cs:

Then, you have to add this new scope to your `Client` using `AllowedScopes` Property in `Config`.cs example:

```
AllowedScopes = { "idade"}
```

Comment: my "AllowedScopes" was only:

                   `AllowedScopes = new List<string>
                    {
                        IdentityServerConstants.StandardScopes.OpenId,
                        IdentityServerConstants.StandardScopes.Profile
                    }`

as I add more than one scope?

Comment: I already tried to change the AllowedScopes but I did not have changes in what is presented.

Comment: you mean you just add it to allowed scopes, but you didn't declare a new scope

Comment: I have already changed the scope according to what is presented in the Identity Server documentation but did not change what is displayed.

Answer (score 1):

If the identity resource is associated with a non-standard claim (e.g. myclaim1), on the client side add the ClaimAction mapping between the claim appearing in JSON (returned from the userinfo endpoint) and the user claim.

```cs
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication
// ...
.AddOpenIdConnect("oidc", options =>
{
    // ...
    options.ClaimActions.MapUniqueJsonKey("myclaim1", "myclaim1");
    // ...
});
```

**Details**

In my case, when I added MiddelName to `TestUser`, it was not displaying on screen:

```cs
new TestUser
{
    SubjectId = "88421113",
    Username = "bob",
    Password = "bob",
    Claims =
    {
        new Claim(JwtClaimTypes.Name, "Bob Smith"),
        new Claim(JwtClaimTypes.GivenName, "Bob"),
        new Claim(JwtClaimTypes.FamilyName, "Smith"),
        new Claim(JwtClaimTypes.Email, "BobSmith@email.com"), 
        //MiddleName added later
        new Claim(JwtClaimTypes.MiddleName, "Bob's middle Name"), 
        new Claim(JwtClaimTypes.EmailVerified, "true", ClaimValueTypes.Boolean),
        new Claim(JwtClaimTypes.WebSite, "http://bob.com"),
        new Claim(JwtClaimTypes.Address, JsonSerializer.Serialize(address), IdentityServerConstants.ClaimValueTypes.Json)
    }
}
```

[image]

If the claims are being returned by userinfo, ClaimsActions are used to map the claims from the returned JSON document to the principal. The following default settings are used here:

```
ClaimActions.MapUniqueJsonKey("sub", "sub");
ClaimActions.MapUniqueJsonKey("name", "name");
ClaimActions.MapUniqueJsonKey("given_name", "given_name");
ClaimActions.MapUniqueJsonKey("family_name", "family_name");
ClaimActions.MapUniqueJsonKey("profile", "profile");
ClaimActions.MapUniqueJsonKey("email", "email");
```

if you are sending a claim to your client that is not part of the above list, it simply gets ignored, and you need to do an explicit mapping. Let’s say your client application receives the website claim via userinfo (one of the standard OIDC claims, but unfortunately not mapped ) – you need to add the mapping yourself:

```cs
options.ClaimActions.MapUniqueJsonKey("website", "website");
```

The same would apply for any other claims you return via userinfo.
Open Startup.cs on Client and apply above step for MiddleName in `ConfigureServices` method:

```
 public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    //...

    options.ClaimActions.MapUniqueJsonKey("middle_name", "middle_name");

    //..
}
```

You will see, website and MiddleName will start appearing

[image]

Reference:
[Interactive Applications with ASP.NET Core](https://docs.duendesoftware.com/identityserver/v5/quickstarts/2_interactive/)